# What's the simplest way to center a headline with a certain width and add margin to it while maintaining cross browser compatible?

Tags: html, css

I've a got a webpage that's built on a framework that claims its already cross browser compatible, however, I'm trying to customize with custom css, I want the headline to align to the center and not to be at 100% width.

I'm using `width: 60%;` and `margin-right: 150px;` to achieve what I want applied to the h1 selector, although it works, it isn't cross browser compatible as when I resize the browser down, it goes all the way to the right.

Please note that, `direction:rtl;` is used.

Comment: can we get a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `text-align:center` to the text. If you have set a width to the text, then

```
.text{
 width:60%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it works! Although the words are breaking line, something to do with the font size, is there anything can be done to this aside from applying @media screen

Comment: @t0r: don't set a width to the text, just use `text-align:center;margin:0 auto;`